# LY L4W Calculation in SQL- Weekly Data

Tags: sql, date, time, google-bigquery

I am using GBQ and trying to figure out a way to calculate YoY changes based on weekly data trying to find last year last week, last year last 2 weeks, ect. My data is a the weekly level and I have columns where I extracted week number and year to help do this. This is easy when using a date in the middle of the year by doing a join like this

```
from tbl a
LEFT JOIN lastyear ly on ly.weeknumber=a.weeknumber and ly.year+1=a.year
LEFT JOIN lastyear_lastweek lylw on lylw.weeknumber+1=a.weeknumber and lylw.year+1=a.year
```

Where this gets complicated is if the week I am looking at is the first or  second week of the year.

For example if I am looking to compare last year last week to week 1 in 2024, I should be comparing to week 52 in 2022. The join I have above does not for for this use case. I don't think I am able to use lag because I have about 20 dimension columns so I would have to partition by all of them.

ex

[image]

The other piece to this is I think it can get more complicated as some years can have 53 weeks. So I can't just do a DATE_ADD 52 weeks to the prev date